# Integrable function in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

There's an exercise in Stein's Real Analysis book that states the following:

The function $f$ given by $f(x) = |x|^{-a}$ if $|x| < 1$ and 0 otherwise, is integrable over $R^d$ if and only if $a < d$.

There's a revised version of this exercise that says the above function $f$ is integrable in $L^p(R^d)$ if, and only if, $pa < d$.

Each of these can be shown by considering sets of the form $E_{2^k} = \{x \colon f(x) > 2^k\}$ and summing over all integers $k$.

There's an adjustment where instead of $f$, we consider the function given by

\begin{equation*}
f_0(x) = \begin{cases}
|x|^{-a}/\log(2/|x|), &\text{if } |x|<1\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Does anyone happen to have any suggestions for when to see that this function is in $L^p$?

Edit:  I can see that this hold if $a \cdot p < d$; however what would happen if $ap=d$? Would it blow up?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just compute. Observe you have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  |f_0(x)|^p\ dx =& \int_{|x|<1} \frac{1}{|x|^{ap}|\log 2-\log |x||^p}\ dx = \int^1_0 \int_{|x|=r} \frac{dS(x)}{r^{ap}|\log 2-\log r|^p}\ dr\\
=&\ \int^1_0 \frac{C_d r^{d-1-ap}}{|\log 2-\log r|^p}\ dr \leq C_d\int^1_0 \frac{dr}{r^{ap-d+1}|\log r|^p} = \int^0_{-\infty} e^{(d-ap)u}|u|^{-p}\ du<\infty
\end{align}
provided $d-ap>0$ and $p<1$.

Comment: Here you applied Fubini's theorem and dS(x) is which measure? I assume it's d-1 dimensional Lebesgue? From what I gathered, the funtion will never be in L^p for $p \gq 1.$

Comment: I used polar coordinates.

Comment: That makes sense, though, I cannot see how you made the conclusions about d-ap and p, since p is assumes to be non-fractional by definition.